# SQL Server CE: Suppress modifications of database file?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

we have an application that has a local SQL Server CE database file. When we open the database, but don't do any changes to it, the database file is changed anyway:

```
using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source='data.sdf';File Mode='Shared Read';Encrypt=FALSE;LCID=1033"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var context = new DataContext(connection))
    {
    }
}
```

This changes some bytes at the very beginning of the sdf-file.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can enable read only mode in the connection string. Also you may need to specify a temp path in this case:

```
string connectionString = ...;Mode = Read Only;Temp Path= ...;
```

[More info.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171817%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I have to be more specific.We can't open the database as read-only. The problem is this: our application uses the database files as document files like MS Word. Therefore, the user could open such a document, edit it and then close it. Our application asks him if he wants to save the changes or discard them. If he discards them, the document, that is the database file, should not have any changes.

Comment: Read only is the only way to avoid file modifications

Comment: Then you should make a backup of the database file before opening connection, and then if there's no changes delete "dirty" database file and rename backed up one to its original name..

Comment: @cyberj0g: Thanks for your clarification and suggestion.